# How to upload image with Strapi and FormData.append

Tags: reactjs, image, upload, field, strapi

I have a problem that I can't solve with Strapi and Reactjs.
How is it possible to access the "image" field of the "Card" array ?

This work perfectly with data structure like :

```
const data = [{
    header: "...",
    content: "...",
    image: "...",
    price: "...",
}];

const updateImg = async value => {
        try {
            setisSending(!isSending);
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('files', value[0]);
            formData.append('ref', 'homepage-content');
            formData.append('refId', id);
            formData.append('field', 'image'); //This field name is ok.
            await axios.post(`${url}/upload`, formData);
            setisSending(false);
        } catch (e) {
            createNotification('error', 'Error message', e);
            setisSending(false);
        }
    };
```

But the problem start with data structure like :

```
const data = [{
    header: "...",
    content: "...",
    Card: [{
        header: "...",
        content: "...",
        image: "...",
    },
    {
        header: "...",
        content: "...",
        image: "...",
    }],
    price: "...",
}];

 const updateImgCard = async (value, index) => {
        try {
            setisSending(!isSending);
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('files', value[0]);
            formData.append('ref', 'homepage-content');
            formData.append('refId', id);
            formData.append('field', `Card[${index}].image`); //This field name seems not to be good.
            await axios.post(`${urle}/upload`, formData);
            setisSending(false);
        } catch (e) {
            createNotification('error', 'Error message', e);
            setisSending(false);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be

```
formData.append('field', `${data[index].Card[index].image}`)
```

Comment: Hi, I have to search inside the Card.

Comment: The file is downloaded but not linked to the card in question.